# Read the below explanation as i don't know how to frame this

Tags: math, statistics, average, mean

i have three columns
a, b, c
and each column have some +ve values, column a is in miles traveled in mode M1, column b is fuel Used in Mode M1/Miles Traveled in mode M1, column c is fuel used in mode M2/ Miles Traveled in mode M2,
now what i am calculating is how much fuel could have been saved if Mode M2 was used throughout that is

**sumover(all the rows individually)(column b* column a - column c* column a)**

if this is +ve which mean we would have save that much fuel if we use mode M2
if this is -ve which mean we would have lost that much fuel if mode M2 was used.

now in my dashboard i am showing that how much fuel is could have been saved.
and its +ve which means using mode M2 would have some benifit.
but when i am calculating the **average values of column b and c i am getting 
**average of c > average of b** ( columns c and b are derived from other four columns like for c its c1/c2 where c1 is fuel used in mode M2 and c2 is mile travelled in M2), each row is having data from different trip. 
** now when calculating average i am either i am doing taking average of columns b and c simply or using the original columns from which these are derived like for c id derived from c1 and c2 so i am doing sum(c1)/sum(c2) ,
but in both the cases i am getting **average of c > average of b**
which is not making sense to the person who is seeing that dashboard like,

**why if the average of b is better than c, how come mode M2(linked with c) is better**

so my question is how to show/calculate the average of columns b and c to make sense.

*** ***** explanation *** *****

a more clear explanation, here column b is for mode M1 and column c is for mode M2

For example

a,  b,   c

10, 5.5, 5.9

50, 6.2, 6.1

difference in fuel consumed for traveling distance in column a

a,  b,   c,    diff

10, 5.5, 5.9,  5.5*10 - 5.9*10

50, 6.2, 6.1,  6.2*50 - 6.1*50

=

a,  b,   c,    diff

10, 5.5, 5.9,  -4

20, 6.2, 6.1,  5

as we see that sum of diff column = 1

which is +ve
and what we are doing here is subtracting c x a from b x a which implies that
over all the trips b is consuming more fuel for the same distance travelled,

but when we calculate the average of b and c

average of b = 5.85

average of c = 6

and we can see that average of b < average of c ?

now this is the issue, what should be the correct way to average of b and c which makes sense, also just to remind you column b and c values are also calculated as mentioned in the main question

Comment: updated the question

Comment: This shows that mode M1 (b) is better for short trips and mode M2 is better for longer ones.

Comment: thanks, for the reply, i found one solution dont know correct or not, in simple average we give equal weights to all the values, but here i saw that the fuel used calculation uses distance  (column a) but while taking average we are not considiring it, so i took weighted average based on that, and now for most of the case the result is making sense.

Comment: dont know if its right or wrong

Comment: That is right. It is what I tried to explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the functions used to calculate the used fuel amount per traveled mile.

Consider the following values rows (a, b, c):

1. (1, 5/1, 2/1)
2. (2, 9/2, 3/2)
3. (100, 100/100, 500/100)

The average for column b is (500+450+100)/100=1050/100; with total fuel used 5+9+100=114.

The average for column c is (200+150+500)/100=850/100, with total fuel used 2+3+500=505.

As you can see column b has a higher (and thus worse) average than column c, even though the total amount of fuel used is lower. So it is entirely possible that one mode has a higher average fuel consumption (for all recorded trips/rows), but still uses less fuel overall.

From above rows you can derive that mode M1 is better than mode M2 for larger values of miles traveled, and vice versa.

If you want to know which mode is better you should just look at the total of fuel used for all trips. You should only compare averages for trips with the same number of miles traveled.

Comment: here you are travelling different distances, for me my first column is distance column on which we need to calculate the fuel used, and the distance is same.

Comment: if every row has the same value for miles traveled (and the values for M1 and M2 are measured instead of calculated) than the explanation still holds but the difference will be far less. But I am curious how you come by the values for M1 and M2 for the same trip.